# Consuming TypeScript Module With baseUrl

Tags: typescript

I have two modules. `ModuleA` uses the `baseUrl` compiler option in its `tsconfig.json` to make `import`s cleaner. Because of this, however, the `.d.ts` files all have the `import` paths relative to the `baseUrl`.

`ModuleB` tries to consume `ModuleA`, and `ModuleA` has been `yarn add`ed to the `ModuleB` project successfully. But when trying to `import ModuleA from "module-a"` into a file in `ModuleB`, TypeScript complains about not being able to find the modules `import`ed in `ModuleA`'s `main.d.ts` file. This is, of course, caused by `ModuleA`'s `.d.ts` files `import`ing relative to the `baseUrl` set in `ModuleA`'s `tsconfig.json`.

I plan on publishing `ModuleA`, so is there anything I can do in `ModuleA` that would allow other modules to consume it properly despite the use of `baseUrl`? If not, is the only recourse to make this easily consumable by other modules to get rid of `baseUrl` and change all of the `import` paths?